# How to check for a value change on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

When this page loads, `GameInfo.roundcounter++;` will always execute. But what i want to do is to increment this value only when correct has changed.

```
public ActionResult Intermediate()
    {
        int correct = GameInfo.correct;
        GameInfo.roundcounter++;


           return View(); 
    }
```

In psuedocode, this is what i want to achieve.

```
if(corrrect > previous.correct) THEN
   INCREMENT GameInfo.roundcounter
```

Can anyone help me in getting this right. Thank you.

Comment: Put it in a if statement? `if (correct > Gameinfo.correct) GameInfo.correct++;`

Comment: are you going back to the controller? or just refreshing the same page?

Comment: @Ben what i want to increment is `GameInfo.roundcounter`. anyway, i don't think that if statement would work because correct will always be equal to 'GameInfo.correct'. but what i want to check for is if `correct` has changed from for instance 1 to 2

Comment: on page refresh i go to the controller @gwilliams

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali Please see updated solution

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

Store the previous correct in ViewBag

```
ViewBag.correct = previous.correct
```

Then evaluate the result later.

```
public ActionResult Intermediate()
{
     If(ViewBag.correct > Gameinfo.correct)
     {
           Gameinfo.correct++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able to do is something like this:

```
// Have two variables: and 'old' and 'new' counter for comparison.
int oldCounter, newCounter = 0;

// Whenever you increment your newCounter, set the value of oldCounter to the previous value of the newCounter
oldCounter = newCounter;
newCounter = //new value;

// Because 'GameInfo.counter' = 'oldCounter', compare it to 'newCounter'
if (newCounter > GameInfo.counter)
    GameInfo.roundCounter++;
```

Comment: new value being `GameInfo.roundcounter++` ? The if statement is always false, and `oldCounter` is always = 0

Comment: No, the `newCounter` and `GameInfo.roundCounter` are two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just test before you assign:

```
private static int correct = 0;
public ActionResult Intermediate()
{
    if (correct != GameInfo.correct)
    {
        correct = GameInfo.correct;
        GameInfo.roundcounter++;
    }
    return View(); 
}
```

And by defining correct outside of the method, as private static, you make it accessible through multiple calls to ActionResult, and not accessible outside of the class that contains this method.  It is then a variable that will remember your last "correct" regardless of what instance of the containing class you are using.